# Get the filename HttpContent in ASP.NET MVC with Xamarin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin

My aplication sends an image in *Xamarin* to my Web API to save the file. I would like to save the file using the filename used in *xamarin* not the name I put in my code.

The code I use in my [webAPI](https://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/handling-images-in-webapi/)

Edit: I solved the problem, addin content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName and getting just the filename, not the complete directory

```
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<MultipartMemoryStreamProvider>(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider()).ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                MultipartMemoryStreamProvider provider = task.Result;
                foreach (HttpContent content in provider.Contents)
                {
                    Stream stream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                    var Name = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                    var NameFinal = Name.Substring(Name.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
                    String filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Fotos/");
                    String fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, NameFinal);
                    image.Save(fullPath);
                }
            });
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: the post you link to shows how to do this by passing a file name in the header

Comment: When i use the original code, the api even save my file =/

Comment: then show us that code so we can help you fix it

Comment: now is the original code and just nothing happens

Comment: Have you debugged it?  Are you passing the filename in the header on the client side?

Comment: I solved the problem, addin content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName and getting just the filename, not the complete directory, thx friend

Comment: @user9991646 Glad sovled it , you can update solution in answer , then mark it 
to be helpful for other people to see how it work .